# Identify chip from picture from STM

Tags: integrated-circuit, stm

I have tried to google the different type of code and I cant really confirm that what I suspect I found is actually the right thing so I might want to see if something can confirm my finidng.

[image]

I suspect this to be a OP-AMP IC from STM from looking up the code number 464. This board is reading RFID chips and connect to STM32 which I suspect my finding is correct.

Is it possible that this is the releated datasheet of this chip? https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/ts464.html

Answer (score 3):

It matches the chip you indicated, TS464CPT
[image]

[Reference for the image](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/STMicroelectronics-TS464CPT/C222172)

Comment: oh great! yeah same :)  do you know what 838 means? Is that a package size ? I couldnt figure out why some have 736 and some 838

Comment: @max246 Likely a lot number. If it's not documented in the datasheet then it's generally not import for identification, but only for the internal tracking by the manufacturer.

Comment: @max246 Digit codes may be date codes, in which case "838" could be 38th week of 2018 (or 2008, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This logo definitely is ST, and a manufacturer will not apply the same marking to different devices. So this datasheet, which confirms "646C", must be the correct one.

Comment: thanks, I was sure the logo was that but I wasnt sure if it was some sort of RF decoder ( which in a way it is from reading a reverse engineering ) so I am glad I can figure out it is a OP-AMP :)